# Vertical alignment in tabular with fbox

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, boxes

I have problems with vertically aligning content in my single row header table for an invoice template.
Currently it looks like this:
 [image: example]
What do I have to do to

1. align the top fbox to the top of the right cell?
2. align the bottom fbox to the bottom of the right cell?

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[MeX]{polski}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

   \setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

   \usepackage[
   top    = 1.50cm,
   bottom = 1.50cm,
   left   = 1.50cm,
   right  = 1.50cm]{geometry}

   \usepackage{tabularx}

   \pagestyle{empty}

   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

   \newcommand{\datasprzedazy}{3.03.2006}
   \newcommand{\terminplatnosci}{17.03.2006}
   \newcommand{\nrfaktury}{3/2006} 
   \newcommand{\netto}{1000.00} 
   \newcommand{\vat}{220.00}
   \newcommand{\brutto}{1220.00}
   \newcommand{\slownie}{jeden tysiąc dwieście dwadzieścia złotych}

   \begin{document}

   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
   \renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}

   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X X }
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
           \fbox
           {
               \parbox[t]{\textwidth}
               {
                   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
                       \begin{tabular}[t]{l l }
                       Company Name & Logo\\
                       Address & \\
                       Street & \\
                       Tax ID &\\
                       Other Info
                       \end{tabular}\par\medskip
                   \end{minipage}  
               }
           }
       \end{minipage}
   &
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
           \framebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{Faktura VAT nr \nrfaktury}} \par
           \begin{tabular}{lr}
           Data sprzedaży: & \datasprzedazy \\
           Data wystawienia: & \datasprzedazy
           \end{tabular}
           \framebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{ORYGINAŁ}} \par
        \end{minipage}
   \end{tabularx}
   \end{document}
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some low level TeX programming makes the job easier: we set the left box (assuming it's the largest with respect to its vertical dimension) with `\hrule` at the top and at the bottom; the first is to set the box with no height, the last one is just for symmetry. More important is the last `\hrule` in the right hand box, that avoids TeX considering the depth of the last inner box.

The right hand box is set in a `\vtop to \dp0`, so it will have the same vertical dimension as the left hand box. Then we typeset the two boxes.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[
  top    = 1.50cm,
  bottom = 1.50cm,
  left   = 1.50cm,
  right  = 1.50cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\datasprzedazy}{3.03.2006}
\newcommand{\terminplatnosci}{17.03.2006}
\newcommand{\nrfaktury}{3/2006} 
\newcommand{\netto}{1000.00} 
\newcommand{\vat}{220.00}
\newcommand{\brutto}{1220.00}
\newcommand{\slownie}{jeden tysiąc dwieście dwadzieścia złotych}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}


\setbox0=\vtop{
  \hrule height 0pt
  \hbox{\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ l l }
      Company Name & Logo\\
      Address & \\
      Street & \\
      Tax ID &\\
      Other Info
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
  }}% end the \fbox and the \hbox
  \hrule height 0pt
  }% end the \vtop

\setbox2=\vtop to \dp0{
  \hrule height 0pt
  \hbox{\framebox[0.47\textwidth]{\textbf{Faktura VAT nr \nrfaktury}}}
  \vfill
  \hbox{\begin{tabular}{lr}
    Data sprzedaży: & \datasprzedazy \\
    Data wystawienia: & \datasprzedazy
  \end{tabular}}
  \vfill
  \hbox{\framebox[0.47\textwidth]{\textbf{ORYGINAŁ}}}
  \hrule height 0pt
  }

\leavevmode\box0\hfill\box2\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a good TeX book, please?

Comment: @phil The TeXbook, of course, but also TeX by Topic that's available on CTAN and in TeX Live.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not a robust solution, but if your invoice template will always have the dimensions you have listed (no text wrapping, extra entries, etc..) then you could just set the right column as

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
    \vspace{-14.5pt}
    \framebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{Faktura VAT nr \nrfaktury}} \par

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
    Data sprzedaży: & \datasprzedazy \\
    Data wystawienia: & \datasprzedazy
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{27pt}
    \framebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{ORYGINAŁ}} \par
 \end{minipage}
```

I will play with it a bit and see if I can come up with something that automatically does this for you.